# New Ubuntu user struggling to add a printer

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I've recently installed Ubuntu as I want to leave Windows. I have an Epson ET-2815 printer. I see from the Epson website that they do not support Linux.

I've done a bit of research and found details of CUPS. I installed CUPS at the terminal following some previously published answers. Using `localhost:631` I followed settings/add printer but although my printer now appears in the list of installed printers it does not accept prints. Well, more correctly, it accepts them and tells me it has printed, but it has not.

At `localhost:631/admin/` I selected ipp and at the following screen I had to identify the connection. I put my IP address `ipp://IPADDRESS:631/ipp/print/` and hit Continue. On the following screen I checked "Share this printer" and hit Continue. On the following screen the installer chose the printer model "EPSON ET-2810 Series, driverless, cups-filters 1.28.15 - IPP Everywhere". I tried to print a document, the printer light flashed and in due course I had a "Printing completed" message on my screen. No print though. Looking at "Modify Printer" in `localhost:631` I see that the current connection is listed as `implicitclass://EPSON_ET_2810_Series%40EPSON03EDB2.local/`.

Can anyone spot where I went wrong?

Comment: What app are you using to try and print?  evince for instance will display a postscript file, but when trying to print, or even preview, will produce a blank page. Other programs like qpdfview works fine.

Comment: try add printer thru gnome settings app

Comment: Specifically, `system-config-printer`

Comment: Look at `/var/log/cups/*`.

Comment: Thank you to all who contributed. I am trying to print from LibreOffice. I have added the printer in Gnome setting but there is no driver available, hence no printing even though the printer is recognised. What is the full path for /var/log/cups/* ? @waltinator and what can I expect there?  I’d assumed it was askubuntu.com/var/log/cups/* but the page is not found.

Comment: I have just resolved this. I search for print apps and installed Gutenprint. Then I went to http://localhost:8000 and then to add printer. Then I gave a name for my printer.  The app searched for a suitable driver but did not find one. I searched the list myself and tried the Epson driver for an Epson printer of the same model range (but not the same model) as mine. It worked first time. Thank you to all for your interest and help.